# CakePHP - get the data from table too

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The function below returns an array with the name of the fields, but I also want to include the data that's in the fields.

How would I do that? I am a newbie to CakePHP.

```
function init_form($models)
{
    foreach($models as $model=> $value) 
    {

        $this->model = new $value; 

        $columns = $this->model->schema(); 

        //Extract field names from array
        $j = 0; 
        foreach($columns as $col => $val) {                 
           $arr[$value][$j] = $col; 
           $j++; 
        } 

        if(!empty($model)) 
        {
            $arr['associated_table'][$value]=$model;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

**FYI:**
I am trying to follow this tutorial
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Gkelly/2006/11/09/report-creator-component

I got it to display the fields name. I am just unable to get the data out.

Thanks

Comment: Provide a little more detail about what you are attempting to do and where the code above is located - Model, Controller?

Comment: code is component. I am calling it from controller. The above link will give you all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `find()` method for [retrieving data from your Model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data).

I am not familiar with the Component you are using. However, considering you have access to the Model with `$this->model`, you can use it's `find()` method just as you are `schema()` - `$this->model->find()`.